# PowerShell and process exit codes

Tags: powershell, error-handling, exit-code

This self-answered question tries to address two distinct aspects of dealing with [process exit codes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exit_status) in PowerShell:

- In PowerShell code, how can you query the exit code set by an external process (a call to an external program), and how do such exit codes integrate with PowerShell's error handling?
- When someone else calls PowerShell via its CLI, [`pwsh`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_pwsh) (PowerShell Core) / [`powershell.exe`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_powershell_exe) (Windows PowerShell), what determines the PowerShell process' exit code  that communicates success vs. failure to the calling process (which could be a build / CI / automation-server task, a scheduled task, or a different shell, for instance).

Answer (score 63, accepted):

<sup>Current as of PowerShell (Core) 7.4</sup>

Note:

- With respect to PowerShell-*internal* use of exit codes, this answer is focused on *directly* calling external (console, i.e. terminal-based) programs (which situationally requires the `&` operator for syntactic reasons), which is the typical use case.
- External programs can also be called via the [`Start-Process`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/start-process) cmdlet, which, however, is rarely the right tool (see [GitHub docs issue #19379](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/PowerShell-Docs/issues/6239) for guidance on when it *is* required / appropriate).

  - If you do need to use `Start-Process` in a given scenario, see [kiloalphaindia's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75971092/45375) for how to obtain the exit code (`$LASTEXITCODE` is *not* populated in that case).

#### PowerShell-*internal* use of exit codes:

**PowerShell-*internally*, where native PowerShell commands generally run *in-process*, exit codes from *child processes* that run *external programs* play a *very limited role***:

- Native PowerShell commands generally don't set exit codes and don't act on them.
- **PowerShell has an *abstract counterpart* to exit codes**: **[`$?`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Automatic_Variables)**, the **automatic, Boolean success-status variable**:
- It reflects whether the most recently executed command had any errors, but in practice it is rarely used, not least because - up to version 6.x - something as seemingly inconsequential as enclosing a command in `(...)` reset `$?` to `$true` - see [GitHub issue #3359](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/3359) - and because using `Write-Error` in user functions doesn't set `$?` to `$false` - see [GitHub issue #3629](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/3629); however, eventually [providing the ability for user code to set `$?` explicitly has been green-lit](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/10917#issuecomment-550550490) for a future version.
- While `$?` also reflects (immediately afterwards) whether an *external program* reported an exit code of `0` (signaling success, making `$?` report `$true`) or a nonzero exit code (typically signaling failure, making `$?` `$false`), it is the **automatic [`$LASTEXICODE`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Automatic_Variables#lastexitcode) variable** that contains the *specific* exit code as an *integer*, and that value is retained until another external program, if any, is called in the same session.

  - **Caveat**: Due to `cmd.exe`'s quirks, a *batch file's* exit code isn't *reliably* reported, but you can work around that with `` cmd /c <batch-file> ... `& exit `` - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55290133/45375); [GitHub issue #15143](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/15143#issuecomment-816105557) additionally suggests building this workaround into PowerShell itself.
  - Also, **up to v7.1, `$?` could report false negatives**, namely if the external program reports exit code `0` while also producing stderr output and there is also a PowerShell redirection involving `2>` or `*>` - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55623532/45375) and [GitHub issue #3996](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/3996#issuecomment-666495478); this has been **corrected in v7.2+**.
  - Finally, it's **best to treat `$LASTEXITCODE` as *read-only*** and let only PowerShell itself set it. (Technically, the variable is writeable and lives in the *global* scope, so if you do want to modify manually, after all, be sure to assign to `$global:LASTEXITCODE`, so as not accidentally create a transient local copy that has no effect.)
- Unlike terminating errors or non-terminating errors reported by PowerShell-native commands, **nonzero exit codes from external programs can *not* be automatically acted upon by the `$ErrorActionPreference` preference variable**, *invariably* so in *Windows PowerShell* and PowerShell (Core) *up to v7.3.x*, and *by default* in v7.4+; that is, you cannot use that variable to silence stderr output from external programs nor can you, more importantly, choose to *abort* a script via value `'Stop'` when an external program reports a nonzero exit code.

  - **v7.4** introduced the [`$PSNativeCommandUseErrorActionPreference` preference variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Preference_Variables#psnativecommanduseerroractionpreference) for ***opt-in* integration of external-program calls with PowerShell's error handling**: If you set this variable to `$true`, it will trigger a PowerShell error<sup>[1]</sup> whenever an external program reports a nonzero exit code, and that error *is* subject to the `$ErrorActionPreference` preference variable. That is, with `$ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'` in effect, any external program reporting a nonzero exit code then causes the script to *abort* by default. (Stderr output prints either way, and separately requires `2>$null` for silencing.)

---

#### How to control what PowerShell reports as *its* exit code when it is called *from the outside*:

**Setting an exit code** that at least communicates success (`0`) vs. failure (nonzero, typically) is an **important mechanism for letting *outside callers* know whether your PowerShell code succeeded overall or not**, such as when being called from a scheduled task or from an automation server such as Jenkins via the **PowerShell CLI** (command-line interface) - [`pwsh`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_pwsh) for PowerShell [Core] vs. [`powershell.exe`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_powershell_exe) for Windows PowerShell.

The CLI offers two ways to execute PowerShell code, and you can **use `exit <n>` to set an exit code**, where `<n>` is the desired exit code:

- `-File <script> [args...]` expects the path of a *script file* (`*.ps1`) to execute, optionally followed by arguments.

  - Executing `exit <n>` *directly* inside such a script file (not inside another script that you call *from* that script) makes the PowerShell process report its exit code as `<n>`.
  - If a given script file exits *implicitly* or with just `exit` (without an exit-code argument), exit code `0` is reported.
- `-Command <powershell-code>` expects a string containing one or more PowerShell commands.

  - To be safe, use `exit <n>` as a direct part of that command string - typically, as the last statement.

**If your code is called from tools that check success by exit code, make sure that all code paths explicitly use `exit <n>` to terminate.**

**Caveat**: If the PowerShell process terminates due to an **unhandled script-terminating error** - irrespective of whether the CLI was invoked with `-File` or `-Command` - the **exit code is always `1`**.

- A script-terminating (fatal) error is either generated from PowerShell code with the `throw` statement or by escalating a less a severe native PowerShell error with 
  `-ErrorAction Stop` or `$ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'`, or by pressing <kbd>Ctrl-C</kbd> to forcefully terminate a script.
- **If exit code `1` isn't specific enough** (it usually *is*, because typically only success vs. failure needs to be communicated), you can **wrap your code in a `try` / `catch` statement and use `exit <n>` from the `catch` block**.

The exact rules for how PowerShell sets its process exit code are complex; find a summary below.

---

#### How PowerShell sets its process exit code:

- If an **unhandled script-terminating error** occurs, the exit code is always `1`.
- With **`-File`**, executing a *script file* (`*.ps1`):

  - If the script ***directly* executes `exit <n>`**, `<n>` becomes the exit code (such statements in *nested* calls are *not* effective).
  - **Otherwise, it is `0`**, *even if non-terminating or statement-terminating errors occurred during script execution*.
- With **`-Command`**, executing a command string containing one or more statements:

  - If an **`exit <n>` statement is executed *directly*** as one of the statements passed in the command string (typically, the *last* statement), `<n>` becomes the exit code.
  - Otherwise, it is the **success status of the *last* statement executed, as implied by `$?`**, that determines the exit code:

    - If `$?` is:

      - `$true` -> exit code `0`
      - `$false` -> exit code `1` - even in the case where the last executed statement was an external program that reported a *different* nonzero exit code.
    - Given that the *last* statement in your command string may not be the one whose success vs. failure you want to signal, **use `exit <n>` explicitly to reliably control the exit code**, which also allows you to report *specific* nonzero exit codes.

      - For instance, to faithfully relay the exit code reported by an external program, append `; exit $LASTEXITCODE` to the string you pass to `-Command`.

---

#### Inconsistencies and pitfalls as of PowerShell 7.0:

- Arguably, `-Command` (`-c`) should report the *specific* exit code of the last statement - provided it has one - instead of the abstract `0` vs. `1`. For instance, `pwsh -c 'findstr'; $LASTEXITCODE` should report `2`, `findstr.exe`'s specific exit code, instead of the abstract `1`  - see [GitHub issue #13501](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/13501).
- Exit-code reporting with `*.ps1` files / the `-File` CLI parameter:

  - It is only an *explicit `exit <n>`* statement that meaningfully sets an exit code; instead, it should again be the *last* statement executed in the script that determines the exit code (which, of course, could be an `exit` statement), as is the case in POSIX-compatible shells and with `-Command`, albeit in the suboptimal manner discussed.
  - When you call a `*.ps1` script via `-File` or as the last statement via `-Command`, PowerShell's exit code in the absence of the script exiting via an `exit` statement is *always `0`* (except in the exceptional <kbd>Ctrl-C</kbd> / `throw` cases, where it becomes `1`).
  - By contrast, when called *in-session*, again in the absence of `exit`, `$LASTEXICODE` reflects the exit code of whatever external program (or other `*.ps1` *if* it set an exit code) was executed last - whether executed inside the script or even *before*.
  - In other words:

    - With `-File`, unlike with `-Command`, the exit code is categorically set to `0` in the absence of an `exit` statement (barring abnormal termination).
    - In-session, the exit code (as reflected in `$LASTEXITCODE`) is *not set at all* for the *script as a whole* in the absence of an `exit` statement.
  - See [GitHub issue #11712](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/11712).

---

<sup>[1] Unfortunately, up at least PowerShell 7.4.0-preview.6, the automatically triggered PowerShell error is a *non-terminating* error rather than a *statement-terminating* one; the latter would make more sense, as it would allow it to be *selectively* caught with a [`try`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Try_Catch_Finally) statement - see [GitHub issue #18368](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/18368).</sup>

Comment: Seem to be an issue with `$LASTEXITCODE` in pwsh, as it reports a large negative number when failing, instead of some small integer. At least when trying on `winget`. That said `$?` works as expected.

Comment: @not2qubit, there's no issue with `$LASTEXITCODE,` it's just that `winget` happens to report large negative numbers. While small numbers are _typically_ used, an exit code can technically be any number that fits into `[int]` (`System.32`)  on Windows (on Unix-like platforms, the range is limited to positive numbers between `0` and `255`).

Answer (score 2):

I think the easiest way is to use `ExitCode` like so:

```
$proc = Start-Process -PassThru cmd
Wait-Process -InputObject $proc
$proc.ExitCode
```

Try this by entering `exit 1` in the `cmd` window.
If you don't wan to issue an additional `Wait-Process`, you can simply pass `-Wait` to `Start-Process` in the first line.

Comment: There is also a `-NoNewWindow` to stop it from making a new window and also `-RedirectStandardXXX` to capure/send IO from/to files.
But you probably know better what you were asking for.

Comment: Good point, but it's not the easiest way, it's an _entirely different use case_: launching a process in a _separate window_ (on Windows), with _no input- and output-stream integration_. 
While `Start-Process -NoNewWindow` can be used to run in the same window, and `-RedirectStandard*` can be used to capture the output streams _in (text-only) files_, `Start-Process` 
is still the wrong tool for invoking _console_ (terminal-based) programs, which should be invoked _directly_, which is the premise of my own answer.

Comment: There are only a few use cases that call for `Start-Process` - see [GitHub docs issue #19379](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/PowerShell-Docs/issues/6239) for guidance; in short: 
You only need `Start-Process` for running a console (terminal-based) program in a _new window_, which includes running with a _different user identity_ (`-Credential`) or _with elevation_ (as admin). This applies to _Windows_ only; on _Unix_-like platforms, `Start-Process` is only ever useful in one case: to launch a GUI application asynchronously.