# Capture exit code from a powershell script in a cmd file

Tags: powershell, batch-file, cmd

I have a simple PS script:

```
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param(
      [Parameter()]
      [String] $CodeCoverageXmlReportPath,
      
      [Parameter()]
      [Int32] $MinimumLineCoverage = 100
    )
    
    Write-Host $"MinimumLineCoverage = $MinimumLineCoverage"
    Write-Host $"Reading CodeCoverage XML report: {$CodeCoverageXmlReportPath}"
    
    ### logic to calculate code coverage from report ###
    
    if ($lineCoverageNum -lt $MinimumLineCoverage)
    {
       Write-Host $"Code coverage of this build ($lineCoverageNum) is below the expected value ($MinimumLineCoverage). Please add tests to validate new code."
       exit 1
    }
    else
    {
       Write-Host $"Code coverage check (($lineCoverageNum)) for this build is at par with the ($MinimumLineCoverage). Great job!."
       exit 0
    }
```

These are the two ways I have tried to execute it from a .cmd file:

```
%SystemRoot%\SysWOW64\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -NonInteractive -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -File ValidateCodeCoverage.ps1 -CodeCoverageXmlReportPath "%TestResultsDir%\Cobertura.xml" -MinimumLineCoverage 57
    
ECHO ErrorLevel=%errorlevel%
```

and

```
%SystemRoot%\SysWOW64\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -NonInteractive -
    ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -Command "& {.\ValidateCodeCoverage.ps1 -CodeCoverageXmlReportPath "%TestResultsDir%\Cobertura.xml" -MinimumLineCoverage 57; exit $LASTEXITCODE}"
    
ECHO ErrorLevel=%errorlevel%
```

In both these cases, checking the value of `%errorlevel%` right after the .ps1 execution remains 0 no matter what. I tried tested it with always exiting with return code 1, using trap, throwing an exception, etc. The %errorlevel%  in cmd file is always set to 0.

What could I be missing? :(

Answer (score 2):

Your PowerShell commands correctly set the exit code, so the problem must be in the way your batch file checks it.

The only scenario in which your code *doesn't* work is if it is **inside a `(...)` block**, where v**ariable references such as `%errorlevel%` are expanded *before* the commands in the block execute**; e.g.:

```
@echo off

REM # Does NOT work as expected, because %ErrorLevel% is expanded 
REM # BEFORE the powershell command excutes.
for /l %%i in (1,1,1) do (
  powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Command "exit 5"
  echo ErrorLevel=%ErrorLevel%
)
```

Output is `ErrorLevel=0`, namely the value of `%errorlevel%` *before* the PowerShell command, which sets the exit code (error level) to `5`, is executed.

To solve this problem:

- You must **use `setlocal enableDelayedExpansion`** at the start of your batch file...

  - Note: The `setlocal` part implies that whatever custom variables you set in your batch file will be local to your batch file, which is generally preferable anyway; see `setlocal /?`
- ... and then **use `!ErrorLevel!` rather than `%ErrorLevel%`**, because only the former guarantees *dynamic* expansion of the error level (exit code):

```
@echo off
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion

REM # OK - thanks to enableDelayedExpansion and !...!,
REM # powershell.exe's exit code is dynamically evaluated.
for /l %%i in (1,1,1) do (
  powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Command "exit 5"
  echo ErrorLevel=!ErrorLevel!
)
```

Output is `ErrorLevel=5`, which now correctly reflects the PowerShell command's exit code.

Comment: Hi @mklement0 nice to see you again, thanks for helping me on my other question. However, in this instance your answer is off.
In my test.ps1 I have:
```exit 10
```
when I execute it:
```powershell -executionpolicy bypass .\test.ps1
   echo %errorlevel%
```
guess what, I get 1. not 10 or whatever number I exit with. I only get 0 or 1.

Comment: You're welcome, @gk_2000. To see a `.ps1` file's exit code, you must invoke it with `-File`: `powershell -executionpolicy bypass -File .\test.ps1`. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57468523/45375) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

SHould have used !var! instead of %var%