# Run command in powershell and ignore exit code in one line

Tags: powershell

I try to execute a command in powershell and ignore any non zeroexit code. Unfortunately I completely fail doing this :-(

Under Linux this is done with this trivial line:

```
command arg1 arg2 || echo "ignore failure"
```

The or clause is executed only in case of a failure and then the exit code of echo resets $?

I thought something like this would do the trick:

```
Invoke-Expression "command arg1 arg2" -ErrorAction Ignore
```

But `$LASTEXITCODE` is still set to a non zero value

Comment: [You need to code your own error handling for terminating and non-terminating errors](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=%27powershell+error+handling%27&t=h_&ia=web). So, try/catch, if/then. If you read the details of ErrorAction, then info and examples explain it's the use case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**PowerShell v7+**'s [pipeline-chain operators, `&&` and `||`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Pipeline_Chain_Operators), implicitly *act* on `$LASTEXITCODE`, but never *reset* it.

If you do want to reset it - which is generally not necessary - you can do the following:

```
command arg1 arg2 || & { "ignore failure"; $global:LASTEXITCODE = 0 }
```

Note that PowerShell scripts - unlike scripts for POSIX-compatible shells such as `bash` - do *not* implicitly exit with the exit code of the most recently executed command; instead, you must use `exit $n` explicitly, where `$n` is the desired exit code.

In the context of calling the PowerShell *CLI* from the *outside*, the above applies to using the `-File` parameter to call a script; for use with the `-Command` (`-c`) parameter, see the next section.

---

As for **what you tried**:

- `||` and `&&` don't work in *Windows PowerShell* (versions up to v5.1) at all.
- `Invoke-Expression` doesn't help here and should generally be *avoided* and used only as a *last resort*, due to its inherent security risks. In short: Avoid it, if possible, given that superior alternatives are usually available. If there truly is no alternative, only ever use it on input you either provided yourself or fully trust - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51252636/45375).

**If you're using the [Windows PowerShell CLI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_powershell_exe) with `-Command` (`-c`), and you need to make sure that the PowerShell process exits with exit code `0`**, do something like the following (`...` represents your command):

```
powershell.exe -noprofile -c "...; exit 0"
```

If you want to comment on the failure:

```
powershell.exe -noprofile -c "...; if ($LASTEXITCODE) { 'ignore failure' }; exit 0"
```

<sup>Note: In this case, `; exit 0` isn't strictly necessary, because the `if` statement alone, due to *it* succeeding, irrespective of the value of `$LASTEXITCODE`, is enough to make the exit code `0`.

Also, note that PowerShell CLI sends all of PowerShell's output streams - including the *error* stream - to *stdout* by default, though you can selective redirect the error stream on demand with `2>`.</sup>

This **also applies to the [PowerShell [Core] v7+ CLI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_pwsh)**, whose executable name is `pwsh`, and whose parameters are a *superset* of the Windows PowerShell CLI.

For more information on PowerShell with respect to process exit codes, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57468523/45375).