# `mypy` returning with exit status of 0 even though code is not properly type hinted in gitlab CI/CD pipeline

Tags: powershell, gitlab, pipeline, mypy

I have the following `.gitlab-ci.yml` file:

```
stages:
  - check-code

before_script:
  - C:\Users\9279\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\profile.ps1
  - conda activate temp

run_tests:
  stage: check-code
  script:
    - pytest test.py

type_checker:
  stage: check-code
  script:
    - (ls -recurse *.py).fullname | foreach-object {echo "`n$_`n";mypy --strict $_}
```

The `check-code` stage runs as expected. However the `type_checker` stage passes in GitLab pipelines even though many of the python scripts in my current directory actually fail the type check.

I suspect this might be because the `(ls -recurse *.py).fullname | foreach-object {echo "`n$_`n";mypy --strict $_}` somehow returns a zero exit code. Is this correct? How can I make sure my pipeline fails when the code is improperly typed?

### Edit

I think the exit code might not be zero after all. I created a temporary script with the following and ran it under the same conditions:

```
(ls -recurse *.py).fullname | foreach-object {echo "`n$_`n";mypy --strict $_}

exit $LASTEXITCODE
```

When I echoed the `$LASTEXITCODE` it contained a value of 1. So now I am quite confused....

Comment: i don't know about powershell but you can keep track of the exit code in a variable like in this bash `res=0; for f in <files>; do <stuff with "$f"> || res=$?; done; $(exit $res)`

Comment: I'm working with powershell right now @joel

Comment: i understand - my thought was that the approach might translate to powershell

Comment: You can simply use the `allow_failure: true` parameter on the CI task.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Presumably, the problem arises because the GitLab CI/CD pipeline executes your PowerShell code via the `-Command` (`-c`) parameter of the PowerShell [CLI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_powershell_exe) (`powershell.exe` for Windows PowerShell, `pwsh` for PowerShell (Core) 7+):

- It is the *last statement executed* that determines the CLI invocation's exit code.
- In your case, that translates to the calls to [`Get-ChildItem`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-childitem) and [`ForEach-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/foreach-object) (`%`): Only if one or both calls *as a whole* are considered to have encountered errors - as reflected in the [automatic `$?` variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Automatic_Variables#section-1) containing `$false` - is `1` reported as the exit code; otherwise, it is `0`.

In other words: the calls to external programs such as `mypy` *inside* the script block passed to `ForEach-Object` have *no* impact on the overall exit code.

To change that, keep track of failing external-program calls and use an explicit `exit` statement as the last statement (code spread across multiple lines for readability - the `;` are only needed if you reformat to a single line):

```
$overallExitCode = 0;
(ls -recurse *.py).fullname | foreach-object { 
  echo "`n$_`n"; mypy --strict $_;
  if ($LASTEXITCODE -ne 0) { $overallExitCode = $LASTEXITCODE }
};
exit $overallExitCode
```

If you only care about the *first* failure:

```
(ls -recurse *.py).fullname | foreach-object { 
  echo "`n$_`n"; mypy --strict $_;
  if ($LASTEXITCODE -ne 0) { break }
};
exit $LASTEXITCODE
```

If you don't care about relaying the *specific* non-zero exit code reported by `mypy` and want to signal *any* failure with overall exit code `1`, you can use the following streamlined formulation (which you've come up with yourself), which relies on the fact that a non-zero exit code reported by calls to external programs also results in `$?` reflecting `$false`:

```
(ls -recurse *.py).fullname | foreach-object {mypy --strict $_; if (-not $?) {exit 1}}
```

For more information about exit codes in PowerShell, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57468523/45375).

Comment: Thanks for accepting, @user32882, and good point regarding the simplification - I've added your command to the answer. Do note, however, that you lose the information about the _specific_ non-zero exit code reported by `mypy` - though I suspect that won't matter.

Answer (score 0):

By default Powershell scripts do not stop on errors. To change this behavior, set the CI/CD variable `ErrorActionPreference: STOP` (for commandlet failures) and/or check `$LASTEXITCODE` and then `throw` if it is nonzero.

If your script is a simple single command, this is not necessary:

```yaml
script: # will succeed/fail depending on exit code of the command
  - some-command-or-executable
```

However, if you call multiple commands/executables in a powershell script and you need your script to exit **immediately** upon any failure, you must check `$LastExitCode` each time and terminate the script manually (using `throw`, `exit` or `$host.SetShouldExit`, etc)

```
some-command
if ($LastExitCode -ne 0) { $host.SetShouldExit($LastExitCode)  }
another-command
if ($LastExitCode -ne 0) { $host.SetShouldExit($LastExitCode)  }
# ...
```

*Without* the `if` conditions, *both* commands would be run regardless of the exit code of the first command (`some-command`). The overall success of the job would be determined by the exit code of the very last command run.

Comment: Then why does the job with `pytest test.py` fail when the exit code is nonzero? That's also technically a powershell script isn't it?

Comment: @user32882 I don't recall the exact distinction, but I believe the difference is whether or not you're using a commandlet and/or the exit code of the _very_ last command. For example doing `pytest` which fails, then any other successful command will result in a success. This is discussed in a few issues: [3134](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-runner/-/issues/3194) [1514](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-runner/-/issues/1514) and is a common behavior of Powershell in [other](https://www.appveyor.com/docs/build-configuration/#script-blocks-in-build-configuration) CI providers.

Comment: Is it common/good practice to set `ErrorActionPreference1` to `STOP`? Or is there a better way? I.e. do I need to adjust that `mypy` call?

Comment: I would say so, but it could be a matter of preference. According to discussion in those linked issues, `ErrorActionPreference` will only affect the behavior of commandlets, not calls to exes like mypy. But maybe it works since you're calling mypy in `for-eachobject`. In general, I believe you must check `$LASTEXITCODE` ([or `$?`](https://techibee.com/powershell/what-is-lastexitcode-and-in-powershell/1847)) each time you call an executable unless it is the only/last command in the script otherwise the job status simply reflects the success/failure of the very last command @user32882

Comment: I actually just set `ErrorActionPreference` to `stop` in my YML file and the behavior is unchanged...

Comment: @user32882 yeah, I believe that's the expected behavior (`ErrorActionPreference` only affects commandlets) you must check `$LASTEXITCODE` manually for executables.

Comment: Why do I not need to check it for `pytest` in that case?

Comment: @user32882 as I understand it, if `pytest` (or any executable) is the very last thing executed in the script, the overall exit code will be `$LASTEXITCODE`. If you add something like `- echo foo` to your script _after_ invoking `pytest` then you should see the same principal problem.