# How do I get the ErrorLevel from a process started via PowerShell Start-Process called from CMD?

Tags: powershell, batch-file, cmd, command-line

I'd like to be able to get the ErrorLevel of Process.exe from this example command:

```
C:\>PowerShell -NoP -C "Start-Process "C:\Process.exe""
```

If Process.exe exits with an ErrorLevel of 5, I'd like to be able to capture that via CMD, ideally in the %ErrorLevel% variable. I'm not proficient enough in PowerShell to do this.

Comment: As an aside: Embedding `"` chars. inside an `"..."` string requires _escaping_ - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49060341/45375).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the following, *assuming that `C:\process.exe` is a *console* application*:<sup>[1]</sup>

```
PowerShell -NoP -C "C:\Process.exe; exit $LASTEXITCODE"
```

<sup>Note: If the executable path contains spaces, enclose it in `'...'`; if it contains `'` itself, either escape the enclosed `'` chars. as `''`, or enclose the path in `\"...\"` (sic) instead - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49060341/45375) for more information.</sup>

In order to get a process' exit code, you must wait for it to terminate.

[`Start-Process`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/start-process) does *not* wait for termination by default, unless you add the `-Wait` switch - but then you'd also need `-PassThru` in order to return a process-information object whose `.ExitCode` property you'd need to report via `exit`.

*Direct* execution of the target executable, as shown above, (a) results in *synchronous* execution of *console applications*<sup>[1]</sup> to be begin with and (b) automatically reflects the process exit code in the [automatic `$LASTEXITCODE` variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Automatic_Variables#lastexitcode) variable.

Without the `exit $LASTEXITCODE` statement, the process' exit code would be mapped to an *abstracted* exit code: `0` (success) would be reported as-is, but *any nonzero* exit code would be mapped to `1` - see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57468522/45375) for more information.

Either way, `PowerShell`'s ([`powershell.exe`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_powershell_exe)'s) exit code will be reflected in `cmd.exe`'s dynamic `%ErrorLevel%` variable.

---

<sup>[1] If your application happens to be a *GUI*-subsystem application, you'll indeed need a `Start-Process`-based solution; as you've noted in a comment yourself, the solution would be:

`PowerShell -NoP -C "exit (Start-Process 'C:\Process.exe' -Wait -PassThru).ExitCode"`</sup>

Comment: Thank you!!
I was accomplish it along with `-Wait` using this command:

`PowerShell -NoP -C "$psErr = (Start-Process 'C:\Process.exe'" -Wait -PassThru).ExitCode; exit $psErr"`.

After that command, it's in `cmd`'s %ErrrorLevel% variable.

Comment: That works too, @Joe, but the solution in this answer is simpler - assuming that `process.exe` is a _console_ application. If not, your solution is indeed the right one.