# Executing powershell command to send email on C# .exe program not working

Tags: c#, windows, powershell, email

I'm using the following command to send an automated email on Powershell.

```
powershell -Command {$to = "myemail@mail.com"; $from = "senderemail@mail.com"; $subject = "subject goes here"; $body = "message body goes here"; $smtpServer = "smtp.server.com"; $smtpClient = New-Object Net.Mail.SmtpClient($smtpServer, 587); $smtpClient.EnableSsl = $true; $smtpClient.Credentials = New-Object System.Net.NetworkCredential("senderemail@mail.com", "Dnd912n9d2n1dsda90"); $smtpClient.Send($from, $to, $subject, $body);}";
```

Here it works. So now I want to use this code on a private way (avoiding showing passwords and emails).

So I made a console app with C# to open Powershell and execute the command, but it's not working.

```
strCmdText = "{$to = \"myemail@mail.com\"; $from = \"senderemail@mail.com\"; $subject = \"subject goes here\"; $body = \"message body goes here\"; $smtpServer = \"smtp.server.com\"; $smtpClient = New-Object Net.Mail.SmtpClient($smtpServer, 587); $smtpClient.EnableSsl = $true; $smtpClient.Credentials = New-Object System.Net.NetworkCredential(\"senderemail@mail.com\", \"Dnd912n9d2n1dsda90\"); $smtpClient.Send($from, $to, $subject, $body);}";

using var ps = PowerShell.Create();

    var processStartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
    processStartInfo.FileName = "powershell.exe";
    processStartInfo.Arguments = " powershell-Command " + strCmdText;
    processStartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
    processStartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;

    using var process = new Process();
    process.StartInfo = processStartInfo;
    process.Start();
```

I'm not receiving any errors on visual studio. if I open .exe it closes inmediatly as if it would be working. But no email is sent or received.

I want to do it by this way because of the privacy the command would have avoiding passwords and emails being shown. Program has to activate when X conditions on computer happen, so it has to execute easy.
Say that if I execute the command on CMD, i receive a different error, that's why I'm doing it on powershell.

Comment: Are you missing a space before "-Command" ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The syntax of the first command you're showing (`powershell -Command { ... }`) works only *from inside a PowerShell session*, not when [`powershell.exe`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_powershell_exe), the Windows PowerShell CLI, is called *from another (non-PowerShell) process*.

Therefore:

- Do not enclose the value of `$strCmdText` in `{ ... }`

  - When the PowerShell CLI is called from the outside, `{ ... }` *creates a [script block](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Script_Blocks)* containing `...` instead of actually *executing* `...`
- `\`-escape all *embedded* `"` chars.

  - On its process command line, the PowerShell CLI requires those `"` characters that are part of the command to execute via `-Command` to be *escaped*, as `\"`.
- Remove the extraneous `powershell` token from `processStartInfo.Arguments = " powershell-Command " + ...`, i.e . use `processStartInfo.Arguments = "-Command " + ...`

  - Strictly speaking, you don't need `-Command`, as it is `powershell.exe`'s *default* parameter; however, using it is a good habit to form, especially since [`pwsh`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_pwsh), the PowerShell (Core) CLI, now defaults to `-File` instead.

To put it all together:

```
// Note the need to escape each embedded " as \\\":
// \ to escape it for the sake of C#,
// preceded by \\ in order to produce verbatim \" in the string value.
strCmdText = "$to = \\\"myemail@mail.com\\\"; $from = \\\"senderemail@mail.com\\\"; $subject = \\\"subject goes here\\\"; $body = \\\"message body goes here\\\"; $smtpServer = \\\"smtp.server.com\\\"; $smtpClient = New-Object Net.Mail.SmtpClient($smtpServer, 587); $smtpClient.EnableSsl = $true; $smtpClient.Credentials = New-Object System.Net.NetworkCredential(\\\"senderemail@mail.com\\\", \\\"Dnd912n9d2n1dsda90\\\"); $smtpClient.Send($from, $to, $subject, $body)";

using var ps = PowerShell.Create();

    var processStartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
    processStartInfo.FileName = "powershell.exe";
    processStartInfo.Arguments = "-Command " + strCmdText;
    processStartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
    processStartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;

    using var process = new Process();
    process.StartInfo = processStartInfo;
    process.Start();
```

Note:

- As long as *launching* `powershell.exe` succeeds, you'll see *no* errors on the C# side, even if the `powershell.exe` call then fails.
- To test for failure:

  - Once `process.HasExited` returns `true`, test `process.ExitCode` for `0` (success) or nonzero (failure).

    - Note that how `powershell.exe -Command` sets its exit code may not be obvious: it is the success status of whatever statement executes *last* that determines the exit code (`0` in case of success, `1` otherwise); if a *fatal* (script-terminating) error occurs (potentially in an earlier statement), the exit code is `1` too - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57468523/45375) for details.
- To examine error messages:

  - Examine the process' *stderr* output.